# RefError when running node populatedb <myMongoDBURL>

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm following the MDN Express tutorial, however I'm encountering an issue using the node populatedb command. It should be populating my mLab database with collections, but it will not and I assume it's due to the aforementioned reference error shown below. If anyone can help me resolve this reference error it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my populatedb.js head:

```
console.log('This script populates some test books, authors, genres and bookinstances to your database. Specified database as argument - e.g.: populatedb mongodb://your_username:your_password@your_dabase_url');

// Get arguments passed on command line
var userArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
if (!userArgs[0].startsWith('mongodb://nathankyle625:*******.@ds137729.mlab.com:37729/local_library_express')) {
console.log('ERROR: You need to specify a valid mongodb URL as the first argument');
return
}

var async = require('async')
var Book = require('./models/book')
var Author = require('./models/author')
var Genre = require('./models/genre')
var BookInstance = require('./models/bookinstance')


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = userArgs[0];
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB 
connection error:'));
```

This is my bookinstance.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BookInstanceSchema = new Schema(
{
book: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Book', required: true }, 
 //reference to the associated book
imprint: {type: String, required: true},
status: {type: String, required: true, enum: ['Available', 
'Maintenance', 'Loaned', 'Reserved'], default: 'Maintenance'},
due_back: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
}
);

// Virtual for bookinstance's URL
BookInstanceSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
return '/catalog/bookinstance/' + this._id;
});

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('BookInstance', BookInstanceSchema);
```

This is what I'm getting upon running the command:

```
express-locallibrary-tutorial nathanbeier$ node populatedb mongodb://nathankyle625:*******.@ds137729.mlab.com:37729/local_library_express  

ReferenceError: BookInstanceSchema is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanbeier/Desktop/express-locallibrary-
tutorial/models/genre.js:10:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanbeier/Desktop/express-locallibrary-tutorial/populatedb.js:15:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but you missed that the error is thrown from `./models/genre.js` file not from `./models/bookinstance.js`, try remove lines with `BookInstanceSchema` from the file `genre.js`, or rename it to `genre.js.save` and try again.

Comment: The issue was in my genre.js file I had a virtual URL set with the BookInstanceSchema. So thank you so much for your help. Works now!